# product create through soap api in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, magento

i want to create product through asp.net.below i wrote code but 102 error getting. can u help me. i don’t understand PHP lang.

```
   string mgntoUsername = “testuser001”; string mgntoAPIkey = “testAPIkey”;
   MagentoService mgntoSrv = new MagentoService(); 
   string mgntoSession = mgntoSrv.login(mgntoUsername, mgntoAPIkey);

   catalogProductCreateEntity mgntoPrdCrt2 = new catalogProductCreateEntity();

   mgntoPrdCrt2.price="12.25"; 
   mgntoPrdCrt2.name = “Atlanta Clear Glazed uPVC Door - test2”; 
   mgntoPrdCrt2.description = “desc - test2”; 
   mgntoPrdCrt2.short_description = “short desc - test2”; 
   mgntoPrdCrt2.weight = “1136”; 
   mgntoPrdCrt2.status = “Enabled”; 
   mgntoPrdCrt2.url_key = “”; 
   mgntoPrdCrt2.visibility = “Catalog, Search”; 
   mgntoPrdCrt2.price = “41.65”; 
   mgntoPrdCrt2.tax_class_id = “none”; 
   mgntoPrdCrt2.gift_message_available = “no”;

   int mgntoResult;

   mgntoResult = mgntoSrv.catalogProductCreate(mgntoSession, “simple”, “”, “sku001-test2”,
mgntoPrdCrt2, “");
```

Comment: I dont know much about .net but, I hope you know how to call soap API in .net right? If yes I can help you out

Comment: hi, thanks. i have solve above question.